# How can I convert to a command in discord.py

Tags: command, discord.py

```
def get_last_trade_price(TICKER):
    Asset = json.dumps(getQuotes(TICKER))
    raw = (json.loads(json.dumps(getQuotes(TICKER)))[0]["LastTradePrice"])
    raw = re.sub(",", "", raw)
    return float(raw)
```

How can I convert this to a discord.py command like prefix and then FRA for the trade price etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already have the `discord.ext.commands.Bot` instance set up properly, you could just use this:

```py
@commands.command(name="last_trading_price")
async def get_last_trading_prive(ctx, ticker):
    raw = (json.loads(json.dumps(getQuotes(ticker)))[0]["LastTradePrice"])
    raw = re.sub(",", "", raw)
    await ctx.send(float(raw))
```

*For the sake of example, assume the command prefix is "!".*

If you were to use the command `!last_trading_price AAPL`, this would send `float(raw)` to the channel which the command was invoked in.